# Can Spring circular reference errors happen randomly due to race conditions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have some builds that are failing with variations of this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'cartServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'addressServiceClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressServiceClient': Bean with name 'addressServiceClient' has been injected into other beans [addressInfoServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

The thing is, we never see this error when we start up the service on our desktops. We only see this error when the build runs on the CI server.  In fact, most of the time when we're building the same code, this error does not occur.  I have a test case where it runs four concurrent builds of the same branch and commit (targeting for deployment to four different clusters), and sometimes all four succeed, but sometimes one (or even two) of them will fail with this error.

My first theory, when I determined the seeming randomness of this, was that there was some screwy problem with our docker registry or docker cache, which was somehow occasionally giving us an older image (there was a related problem of this nature, for real, several weeks ago).  Despite my desire to hang this on another team, I have to assume that there's something we're doing that could be causing this, but perhaps it's random because this is depending on a race condition.  I find it hard to believe that Spring bean resolution could have race conditions.

Is there any possibility that an error like this might occur or not occur, depending on race conditions?

We're using Spring Framework 5.0.9 with Spring Boot 2.0.5.

**Update**:

Note that I still can't repeat this problem with ordinary testing on my laptop, but we were able to extract the jar file constructed on the CI server and download it to my laptop, and then run that directly, and it does get the same error.  We compared the contents of the jar file between that jar and a "good" one, and the differences were subtle, no obvious problems that might cause this.  We did notice that the `AddressServiceClient` mentioned in the error is second in the list of classes in the "bad" jar, and far down the list in the "good" jar.

I then thought that perhaps adding `@Lazy` to the `AddressServiceClient` class would avoid the problem (not that I don't say "fix").  I tried modifying that "bad" jar file locally, using "zip" to update the jar file with the updated class file, and I found that that resulting jar file did NOT demonstrate the symptom.  However, when I finally merged the PR with this change and the builds ran on the CI server, one of them still failed with the same error.

Comment: No, a circular reference can never happen if everything is structured correctly. The only reason I can think that you wouldn't consistently see this is if you lazily load some classes/beans and they are only initialised under certain conditions.

Comment: And isn't the presence of constructor injection something that can lead to this?  I didn't find any constructor injection in our source, but I found several in the platform libraries we use (developed by another team).

Comment: It happens through dependency injection. Are you using AOP?

Comment: Uh, yeah, I know it happens through DI. Not sure why you said that. No, we're not using AOP.

Comment: I said that since you asked` is the presence of constructor injection something that can lead to it`. It literally just happens if you have dependencies injected in a circular fashion. Honestly if you have the code and that error pointing out the classes it should be immediately obvious what is causing it.

Comment: If you have circular dependencies, time to a refactor!

Comment: 123, I wish it were that simple. We've been unable to find the cycle.  It may be hard to find if the cycle is "deep".  I thought that perhaps adding @Lazy to the AddressServiceClient would avoid the problem, but it still happens.

Comment: Adding `@Lazy` won't solve a thing. The bean will still be initialized because it is needed. What you should do instead is mark the field (or constructor argument with `@Lazy`). That will create a proxy for your bean which will be lazily resolved once it is needed.

Comment: Initial testing verifies this, but it's hard to tell for sure, considering the semi-random nature of this.  To be clear, you're saying that Lazy on the class makes no difference, but Lazy on the field does. I was almost hoping this wouldn't work, so we would be forced to truly bear down and find and fix the cycle, but that will be extremely painful.

Comment: I believe the answer to the question title is **yes**. I can't say that it happens _randomly_, but 'circular dependency' errors can be triggered (or not) based on subtle, non-functional, differences (such as CPU power) between environments with no changes to the build.

Comment: I have seen intermittent failures due to circular references, and the ordering of the class files within the jar file appeared to be significant.  By removing a file and adding it back, a broken jar would then work.  A lack of deterministic order in which files get added to the jar may lead to the "randomness".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setter` injection, it use Spring `L3 Cache`.
For example:

```java
    private TmsOrderService tmsOrderService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTmsOrderService(TmsOrderService tmsOrderService) {
        this.tmsOrderService = tmsOrderService;
    }
```

Spring `L3 Cache` avoid circular dependencies.