# Spring circular reference error only happens some of the time, and @Lazy has no effect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I asked a recent question about Spring circular reference issues, but I didn't get anything useful from that. I'm going to restate the current problem with additional information.

I'm using Spring 5.0.9 (also tried 5.2.5) and Spring Boot 2.0.5.

When we merge code to master, a build of the same code starts on four different dev servers.  Very often, sometimes on only one server, sometimes on two, we get an error like the following:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'billPreferenceRestService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'componentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stateManagerOperation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'addressServiceClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressServiceClient': Bean with name 'addressServiceClient' has been injected into other beans [addressInfoServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped.
```

It doesn't happen on the same server each time.  Invariably, if we simply request the build to be rerun on that server, the error doesn't happen.

I have spent a long time looking at bean references, centering on the `addressServiceClient` bean, which seems to always be part of this, and I cannot find a circular reference, but it could be several levels deep, which makes it very hard to find.

We never see this error with normal testing on our laptops, it only ever happens on the build server.  However, I was able to extract the fat jar that is constructed on the server and download it to my laptop, and when I execute that from the command line, it does demonstrate the same error.  I've also done the same with the fat jar on builds that do NOT demonstrate the error, and it does not show the error running on the laptop.  If I compare the "bad" jar with the "good" jar, I only see differences in the order of entries in the archive.

Since the `AddressServiceClient` always seems to be involved in this alleged cycle, I decided to add `@Lazy` to the class declaration.  This had no effect.

After that, I set up the application so that if any parameters were passed in (normally no command-line parameters are supplied), instead of doing a normal startup of the application, it would instead execute the following loop (paraphrased somewhat from the real code):

```
for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(basePackage)) {
  String beanClassName = bd.getBeanClassName();
  System.out.println("cn[" + beanClassName + "] lazy[" + bd.isLazyInit() + "] dependsOn[" + bd.getDependsOn() + "]");
}
```

Note that if it executes that code, it doesn't execute the normal startup code, which is approximately this:

```
getSpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Application.class).run(args);
```

Where `Application` has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

I executed the "bad" jar on my laptop with a dummy command-line argument so it would execute this code.  I searched through the output for the `AddressServiceClient` class.  The `lazy` flag was `false` (and `dependsOn` was null).

I suppose the the `lazy` flag isn't `true` because by not executing `run()` on the `SpringApplicationBuilder`, I skipped some bean resolution steps.  I could use confirmation of that.

Note that none of our application classes are using constructor injection.  Some of the constructors in some of the platform libraries we use (written by another team) are using constructor injection, but I examined each one of those, and they're either injecting simple properties or objects that couldn't possibly be in our cycle.

We are not using AOP.

I could some ideas.  Don't bother suggesting that I refactor. That is pointless if I don't know what I need to refactor to solve this problem. The overall application is quite large.

Comment: You didn't notice that I asked that question?

Comment: Yep, you've asked the same question, if you had more details you should have updated the previous one.

Comment: Have a look at this https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot/archives/2017/07/20

Comment: gitter is blocked by our firewall, but I browsed that on my phone. That confirms that this could fail sometimes and not other times, but that's about all that tells me.

Comment: I wonder if there's any way that adding @DependsOn to particular classes could force a particular resolution order that would resolve this.  I have no idea what ordering I need to force yet.

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089599/can-spring-circular-reference-errors-happen-randomly-due-to-race-conditions) again. Instead modify that question with additional information!